# Downloading a lot of files with libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am trying to downloading a lot of files from a website. I am recursively going from page to page and extract link from there. And after I downloaded
543 files (I've tried several times and the number is always the same), 
I got a error code 2, which refers to CURLE_FAILED_INIT.

Piece of code, which downloaded a file (copy-paste from one of the tutorial):

```
CURLcode curl_read(const std::string& url, std::string& buffer, long timeout = 30) {
    CURLcode code(CURLE_FAILED_INIT);
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    if(curl) {
        if(CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str()))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, string_write))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout))) {

          code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error inside setting curl" << std::endl;
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Error inside curl_easy_init" << std::endl;
    }
    return code;
}
```

Before this code run, I called

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
```

Comment: You need to restructure the code (or use debugger) to understand which exact call fails.

Comment: In general, the `curl_easy_setopt` return codes are not used, but the result of `curl_easy_perform` are checked against whatever behavior you want. Considering that you initialize the `CURLcode` with the value `CURLE_FAILED_INIT`, I would guess that has some effect on your error.

Comment: Print the url that it is trying to connect to.

Comment: You should reuse the 'code' handle much better instead of creating/deleting them for each URL. It'll increase your performance greatly.